# Is there actually exist a computable function that take any argument （such as real number)?But how can it be proved？

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computability, recursion, turing-machines, lambda-calculus

First，i do not understand why the recursion equals computable.when i was study the computable function，could it is defined in the real number set?(recursion function is defined in natural number.Finally,how can we prove there is exist a computable function that take any argument （such as real number) by turing machine or lambda calculus model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reese already discussed what Turing called "o-machines" ("o" for "oracle"); another standard way to describe them is as having *two* tapes, one of which is "read-only" and has the bits of the input real printed on it. With work, we can even view o-machines as coding functions from reals to reals - see e.g. [computable analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a77d/066d00771a837da87ad82543486a8a2c5215.pdf).

Another approach is that of [Blum-Shub-Smale](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183555121), or equivalently and slightly more generally [Friedman](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1992-332-01/S0002-9947-1992-1055807-7/S0002-9947-1992-1055807-7.pdf). Roughly speaking, a Turing machine works over the "structure" $\{0, 1\}$ equipped with the "swap" function $s:0\mapsto 1, 1\mapsto 0$; the operations a Turing machine can perform on a single cell are either leave it unchanged, or apply swap. This can be generalized to describe Turing machines based on any first-order structure (say, a ring or field, as in the case Blum-Shub-Smale focus on). See e.g. the book [Complexity and Real Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982817). This approach has a number of differences from the more traditionally Turing-based computable analysis, mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "if the recursion is necessary for computable"; generally, "recursive" and "computable" are considered synonyms.

The Turing machine model can sort of handle real arguments - what you can do is write out the real number in binary on the machine's tape before the machine begins to run. But that means that you can't expect it to read the entire real, output another real, and then halt - in order to read the input real, it must take infinitely many steps. This means that, for example, a Turing machine would not be able to tell that $0.1111\ldots$ and $1.0000\ldots$ denote the same real number.

If you want a model of computation that can handle real numbers in the way that most casual observers would consider "natural" - that is, a model that allows you to input a real and get a real out, which allows checking whether two reals are equal or doing elementary operations like addition - you have to look at other approaches. If you're at a graduate level of education or higher, I'd recommend *Effective Mathematics of the Uncountable* as a resource for these; but it's a bit more advanced than I'd suggest for a beginner.

So, to answer your question more directly: If we are only considering the standard Turing machine model of computation - or, equivalently, lambda calculus - only natural numbers can be taken as arguments. This isn't as limiting as it sounds; since we can "encode" an entire sentence as a natural number, we can give a natural number that "represents" any real number you care to name (for example, perhaps $\pi$ is represented by the number $1609$, directly translating the letters PI into two-digit numbers).

Comment: "Any real you care to name" doesn't cover all real numbers. Also there are uncomputable but name able reals such as Chaitin's constant.

Comment: @QThePlatypus Chaitin's constant is not *precisely* nameable, only loosely describable. And you're correct that not every real is approachable; this is why I said "any real you care to name" and not "any real". Perhaps I should have been clearer.

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by "nameable" - personally I'd argue it *is* nameable. Also, I second both the recommendation for the EMU book, and the cautionary note; in particular, I think the OP might be interested in Russell Miller's notion(s) of [local computability](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~rmiller/LocalChap.pdf).

Comment: @Reese Computability and Recursion is little different as i learned from (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/comprec.pdf ).When the recursion is mentioned,it always need to study with the natural number.So how can we talk about the computability with real number.I do not kown if i am right.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I suppose for this context I'd say "nameable" has to mean "nameable in such a way that a Turing machine can use the name to perform computations involving the real". Good point about local computability, and BSS machines below.

Comment: @Lufamily Ah, I see. Yes, recursion in that sense is limited to natural numbers; computability is limited in the same way, under either of the models you mentioned. The only way to talk about computability on real numbers is to either use an alternate model of computing (like the ones I mentioned, or Noah's suggestion below) or to use some sort of "trick" (like using "names" for reals, which as Q above pointed out does not allow you to work with all reals).